# Swagger not allowing retrieval when using JWT Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am still getting 401 unauthorized When I send my token across to my api via swagger

> content-length: 0   date: Sat, 06 Jun 2020 12:51:50 GMT   server:
>   Microsoft-IIS/8.5   strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000
>   www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
>   signature is invalid"   x-powered-by: ASP.NET

This is my ConfigureServices Config

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
 c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "App Manager - Running Buddies", Version = "v1" });
 c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT"

            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement{
   {
    new OpenApiSecurityScheme{
        Reference = new OpenApiReference{
            Id = "Bearer", //The name of the previously defined security scheme.
            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
        }
    },new List<string>()  }
    });


        });

        services.AddTokenAuthentication(Configuration);
```

My AddTokenAuthentication call which is extension to configure the authentication JWT Bearer can swagger not allow the testing when its a barrer token

```
 public static class AddTokenAuthentications {
    public static IServiceCollection AddTokenAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config) {
        var secret = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("SecretKey").Value;
        var keySecret = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(secret);

        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keySecret.ToString());
        services.AddAuthentication(x => {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
               .AddJwtBearer(x => {

                   {

              //        x.Audience = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Audience").Value;
                    //   x.Authority = config.GetSection("JwtToken").GetSection("Authority").Value;

                       x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                       x.SaveToken = true;
                       x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
                           ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                           IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                           ValidateIssuer = false,
                           ValidateAudience = false
                       };
                   }
               });

        return services;
    }
```

As you can see the barrer token is in the curl statment so it should be authorised

> curl -X GET "https://******/api/BmiInformations/bmi/all" -H "accept:
>   text/plain" -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTE0NDk5NjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLWZpdG5lc3NidWRkaWVzLm5ldCIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLWZpdG5lc3NidWRkaWVzLm5ldCJ9.txG4OUUcfOqdDSBvPWJTuMaQ0RbThbvQwPiwgAleUrk"

**Edit 2**
As you see here the jwt token is valid

https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTE0NjEwNzksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0Mzk2LyJ9.pkw-RisnhJ6J2XuC8tynFeiN_zEygYblulNA4mqRbac

Comment: which swagger library are you using? swashbuckle?

Comment: Yes Swashbuckle

Comment: The *** are simply me hidding my confidential passwords at presnet from google and stack

Comment: could you please show me how you do the authorization?

Comment: The authorisation works as says its works in app just not in postman.

Comment: if it works in app but failed to authorized with postman, did you check the differences between both header in requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215432/discussion-between--and-rogue39nin).